# Laravel image upload

Tags: php, image, http, laravel, network-file-transfer

I'm new to the filesystem from Laravel, but I need an upload script that allows users to upload images to my server. However, i'm concerned about securety, so I thought why not ask for advice, because there aren't much reverences about that big topic of securety.

Basicly, this is how I check the user upload and how I upload the file:

My request Class:

```
 return [
        'profile_picture' => 'image',
    ];
```

My check if the image is actually an image and not some bad maleware:

```
function checkIfImageIsAllowed($file) {
$allowedMimes = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/png'
];

$allowedExtensions = [
    'jpg',
    'JPG',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
];
$allowedMaxSize = 2000000;
if(!in_array($file->getClientOriginalExtension(), $allowedExtensions) || !in_array($file->getMimeType(), $allowedMimes) || $file->getSize() > $allowedMaxSize) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

And than I upload the file:

```
$path = $request->file('profile_picture')->store('UserUpload/Images');
```

This is how I display the Image:

```
    $images = \App\Image::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
    $path = $images->path;
    $image = Storage::get($path);
    $response = Response::make($image, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $images->memeType);

    return $response;
```

What are your thoughts about this? Do you think this is secure enough? Or do you have some improvement for this?

Comment: `image/jpg` mime type doesn't exist. Both extensions [use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) `image/jpeg`. Also you should have lower cases only in extensions array and check it with `!in_array(strtolower($file->getMimeType()), $allowedMimes)`.

Answer (score 2):

The code can be made simpler by using some built-in Laravel validation rules:

- Validation of MIME types and extension can already be done in Laravel.

  With the rule `image` as you have for `profile_picture`, you're already validating if the uploaded file is of the mimetype `jpeg`, `png`, `bmp`, `gif`, or `svg` (docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-image)). If you'd like to specify the mimetype however, you can use the [mimes rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-mimes).
- To validate the max size of the image, you can use the [max rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-max).
- You can also validate the dimensions of the image if needed (docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-dimensions)).

---

On the matter of security, I suppose you mean with the uploading of the images. The snippets of code you provided do seem enough (have not perused it), but I would advise using the built-in validation provided by Laravel to provide the best of convenience and security.